# Swap the Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Your task is to write some code that outputs an OEIS sequence, and contains the name of the sequence in the code (`A______`).  Easy enough right?  Well here's the catch, your code must also output a second separate sequence when the name of the sequence in the code is changed to the name of the second sequence.

### Input Output

Your code can be a function or complete program that takes **n** via a standard input method and outputs the **n**th term of the sequence as indexed by the provided index on the OEIS page.

You must support all values provided in the OEIS b files for that sequence, any number not in the b files need not be supported.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score will be the number of bytes in your code, with less bytes being better.

### Example

Here's an example in Haskell that works for A000217 and A000290.

```hs
f x|last"A000217"=='0'=x^2|1>0=sum[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoiYnsbhEydHAwMDI0FzJ1lbdQN22Is6oxtDOwLa4NDfaUE@vIvZ/bmJmnm1BUWZeiUqagqHBfwA)

Comment: To clarify: Your code should work for two sequences where putting the name of the sequence in that part of the code will output the number of that sequence?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yes.  When the name of the sequence is substituted in it should change the function of the program to be the second sequence.

Comment: Do the sequences in the code have to have leading zeros.

Comment: @ppperry Yes it should.

Comment: Is the `A` required?

Comment: @Okx Yes it is.

Comment: If the sequence number appears more than once, does every instance change to the new sequence number?

Comment: @EngineerToast No it does not have to.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
n=>4&~0xA000004
```

Works with A000004 (all 0s) and A010709 (all 4s).

Previous 17-byte solution works with A010850 to A010859 inclusive:

```
n=>~-0xA010850%36
```

Previous 25-byte solution works with A010850 to A010871 inclusive:

```
n=>"A010850".slice(5)-39
```

Comment: This is just showing off (I don't know OEIS well enough to see how clever this is :P)

Comment: Strange -- two answers started at 25 bytes and were both golfed to 17 bytes in a minute

Comment: @ppperry Heh, but I could port your answer and it would be only 15 bytes...

Comment: JS tied with [Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137226/58974)?! Very nicely done

Comment: @Shaggy Nope; a new shorter jelly answer was posted.

Comment: @ppperry, let us JSers have our moment! :p

Comment: @Shaggy Tell Erik the Outgolfer ...

Answer (score 6):

## C#, 28 bytes

```c#
n=>n*n*("A000290"[6]<49?1:n)
```

Works with [A000290 (Squares)](https://oeis.org/A000290) and [A000578 (Cubes)](https://oeis.org/A000578).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv2fl5ibWlyQmJyqEFxZXJKay1XNpQAEyTmJxcUKAWA2RAQEiksSSzKTFcryM1MUfBMz8zQ04VIIRSDgVpqXbJOZV6KjACTsFNIUbBX@59na5WnlaWkoORoYGBhZGihFm8XamFjaG1rlaf635kLR75yfV5yfk6oXXpRZkuqTmZeqkaZhpKlpTVCRMTGKTIhRZApShFVVUGpiClgRkim1XBCy9j8A)

Comment: Nice job using a non-constant sequence.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 28 bytes

```
f x|"A000012"!!6<'3'=1|1<2=x
```

The second sequence is A007953. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hokbJ0QAIDI2UFBXNbNSN1W0NawxtjGwruNKhkuaWpsbokv9zEzPzFGwVUvK5FBQKijLzShRUFHITCxTSFKIN9fQMDWLRxNNh4v8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 16 bytes

```
=A000007//5#|A:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bRAATM9fVNlWscrQz@/zcEAA), [A000007](https://oeis.org/A000007), `1,0,0,0,0...`

```
=A000004//5#|A:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bRAARM9PVNlWscrQz@/zcEAA), [A000004](https://oeis.org/A000004), `0,0,0,0,0...`

### Explanation

```
                    Implicit input A
=A000007            First item in the sequence equals A * 7
        //5                                                 intdiv 5 = 1
           #|A      n equals A
              :     Mode : (sequence): output nth item (1-based)
               0    Rest of the sequence is 0
```

```
                    Implicit input A
=A000004            First item in the sequence equals A * 4
        //5                                                 intdiv 5 = 0
           #|A      n equals A
              :     Mode : (sequence): output nth item (1-based)
               0    Rest of the sequence is 0
```

Thanks to Conor O'Brien for `4//5 = 0` and `7//5 = 1`.

If the spec was more flexible, it would be `O7A$` and `O4A$`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 28 bytes

```
I:uU**...L..A000578@O\s<s(;?
```

returns the [perfect cubes](https://oeis.org/A000578), `a(n)=n^3`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/TqjRUS0tPT89HT8/RwMDA1NzCwT@m2KZYw9r@/38TAA)

On the other hand,

```
I:uU**...L..A068601@O\s<s(;?
```

returns the [perfect cubes minus one](https://oeis.org/A068601), `a(n)=n^3-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 13 bytes

**Edit:** Apparently OEIS lists the powers from `0`th to `30`th - I just did a search on these sequences and it turns out the original `13` byte solution is the golfiest. But I found another solution for just `1` byte more that works for `9` sequences.

Solution for [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012) (constant 1's sequence):

```
?A000012 4%^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/e0QAIDI0UTFTjCv7/NwUA)

Solution for [A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477) (non-negative integers):

```
?A001477 4%^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/e0cDA0MTcXMFENa7g/39TAA)

Solution for [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290) (perfect squares sequence):

```
?A000290 4%^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/e0cDAwMjSQMFENa7g/39TAA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

These solutions make use of the fact that `dc` interprets `A` as `10`, so `A001477` becomes the value `10001477`. Further it exploits that the sequences are `n^0`, `n^1` and `n^2` which coincides with `10000012 % 4 == 0`, `10001477 % 4 == 1` and `10000290 % 4 == 2`.

So these sequences are `xyz(n) = n ^ (xyz % 4)`.

```
Command          Description          Example (3) 
?              # Push the input       [3]
 A000290       # Push sequence name   [3,10000290]
         4%    # Top %= 4             [3,2]
           ^   # Pop x,y & push y^x   [9]
            p  # Print the top        [9]
```

#### 14 byte solution for 9 sequences

The idea is still the same, this time we need to do a `% 97`, to get the right power - it works for sequences [A010801](https://oeis.org/A010801), [A010802](https://oeis.org/A010802), [A010803](https://oeis.org/A010803), [A010804](https://oeis.org/A010804), [A010805](https://oeis.org/A010805), [A010806](https://oeis.org/A010806), [A010807](https://oeis.org/A010807), [A010808](https://oeis.org/A010808) and [A010809](https://oeis.org/A010809) (these are the sequences `n^13`,...,`n^21`).

Here's the first one:

```
?A010801 97%^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/e0cDQwMLAUMHSXDWu4P9/IwA)

Comment: +1 for supporting more than two sequences!

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
A000012ᛄ>
```

Explanation:

```
A            Push 42
 000012      Push 4
 or
 A007395     Push 7395
        ᛄ     Modulo 2
         >    Increment
```

A000012 (all ones) and A007395 (all twos)

A function that takes the input on the top of the stack and leaves the output on the top of the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/39EACAyNHs5usfv/3xgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>25</s> 17 bytes

```
print'A000012'[5]
```

Works for A000004 and A000012. (input is ignored because the sequences are all constant terms).

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98, 10 bytes

```
#A000012$q
```

Also works for A000004. Output by exit code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
“A000578”OS%⁵ạ6*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxxHAwMDU3OLRw1z/YNVHzVufbhroZmWw////00B)

```
“A000578”OS%⁵ạ6*@  Main link
“A000578”          String
         O         Codepoints
          S        Sum (364 for A000290, 373 for A000578)
           %⁵      Modulo 10 (4 for A000290, 3 for A000578)
             ạ6    Absolute Difference with 6 (2 for A000290, 3 for A000578)
               *@  [left argument] ** [result of last link (right argument)]
```

Also works with A000290

Comment: Good job using non-constant sequences.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
+(0xA000012-eq160mb+18)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1vDoMLRAAgMjXRTCw3NDHKTtA0tNP///28KAA)

Uses [A000012](http://oeis.org/A000012) (the all ones sequence) and [A000004](http://oeis.org/A000004) (the all zeros sequence).

Leverages several neat tricks. We use `0x` as the hexadecimal operator onto the sequence which gives us `167772178`. That's compared to see if its `-eq`ual to `160mb+18` using the `mb` operator (`160mb` is `167772160`). That Boolean result is then cast as an int with `+` to output the proper `1` or `0`. Note that *any* sequence in the code other than A000012 will result in `0` being output.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
A000012₉/
```

Works with [A000012](http://oeis.org/A000012) and [A000004](http://oeis.org/A000004).

[Try A000012!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/39EACAyNHjV16v//bw4A)

[Try A000004!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/39EABEweNXXq//9vDgA)

#### Explanation

```
A          Undefined (ignored)
 000012    Push 12
       ₉   Push 9
        /  Integer division, results in 1
```

```
A          Undefined (ignored)
 000004    Push 4
       ₉   Push 9
        /  Integer division, results in 0
```

Comment: Why does everyone keep posting A00004 and A00012?

Comment: @ppperry  A000004 is the zero sequence and A000012 is the ones sequence. Simply floor divide the numbers by 9 and output the result forever.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 12 bytes

```powershell
'A000012'[5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X93RAAgMjdSjTWP///9vaAoA)

Works for A000012 (the all ones sequence) and A000004 (the all zeros sequence).

Port of [ppperry's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137217/42963).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
A000004¨θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0QAETA6tOLfj/39DAwA)

Works for A000004 and A000012.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
6ị“A000004
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/s4e7uRw1zHA1AwOT///@GBgA)

Works for A000004 and A000012.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 10 bytes

```
A000004X.⌂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/RAARMIvQe9TT9/29oAAA)

Works for A000004 and A000012.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
@"A000004"5
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%22A000004%225&input=10&debug=0)

Supports A000004 and A000012.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

Both solutions are `1`-indexed.

This works for [A000351](https://oeis.org/A000351) (powers of 5):

```
!¡*i!6"A000351"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQQq1MRTMlRwMDA2NTQyXD////GwMA)

And this one for [A000007](https://oeis.org/A000007) (powers of 0):

```
!¡*i!6"A000007"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQQq1MRTMlRwMQMFcy/P//vzEA)

#### Explanation

It makes use that the names [A000351](https://oeis.org/A000351), [A000007](https://oeis.org/A000007) contain the right digit D at the position 6, such that the sequence is `D^0,D^1,D^2,...`:

```
                  -- implicit input N
   i!6"AxxxxDx"   -- get the right digit D and convert to number,
 ¡*            1  -- iterate (D*) infinitely beginning with 1,
!                 -- extract the value at Nth position
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

This one returns a bit more interesting sequences, again solutions are `1`-indexed.

This works for [A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040) (the prime numbers):

```
!!i→"A000040"e:0İfİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X1Ex81HbJCVHAyAwMVBKtTI4siHtyIaC////GxoDAA)

And this one for [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) (the Fibonacci numbers):

```
!!i→"A000045"e:0İfİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X1Ex81HbJCVHAyAwMVVKtTI4siHtyIaC////GxoDAA)

#### Explanation

This makes use of the fact that the last digit of the sequence names have a different parity:

```
                      -- implicit input N
             e        -- construct a list with:
              :0İf    --   list of Fibonacci numbers (prepend 0)
                  İp  --   list of the prime numbers
  i→"Axxxxx?"         -- get the last character and convert to number,
 !                    -- use it as modular index (0 -> primes, 5 -> Fibonacci)
!                     -- get the value at the Nth index
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 40 bytes

```
a:=SubStr("A000004",6)//9
Loop
Send %a%,
```

Output: `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...`

```
a:=SubStr("A000012",6)//9
Loop
Send %a%,
```

Output: `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...`

This might not be the shortest code but I bet it's the shortest sequence pair we can find. [A000004](https://oeis.org/A000004) is the zero sequence and [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012) is the ones sequence. Simply floor divide the numbers by 9 and output the result forever.

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 28 bytes

```
p=!_s@A000035`,-1|!?:%2+5-p
```

This switches between the sequences [A000034](https://oeis.org/A000034) (1, 2, 1, 2, 1 ...) and [A000035](https://oeis.org/A000035) (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ...)

### Explanation

```
p=                  Set p to 
  !            !    A numeric representation of
   _s         |     a substring of
     @A000035`      our sequence code (either A0035 or A0034)
     ,-1            taking just one character from the right.
?:%2                PRINT <n> MOD 2 (gives us a either 0 or 1)
    +5-p            Plus 1 for seq A24 (5-4), or plus 0 for A35
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

[A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027) The positive integers

```
A000027 3\Gw-&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39EACIzMFYxj3Mt11f7/NwUA)

[A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477) The nonnegative integers

```
A001477 3\Gw-&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39HAwNDE3FzBOMa9XFft/39TAA)